# What is the difference between template_preprocess_search_result() and template_preprocess_search_results()?

Tags: 7, search, theming

I am seeing 2 functions like `template_preprocess_search_result()` and `template_preprocess_search_results()` in Drupal 7. I just got confused on which function I should use when modifying my search results.

Can anyone tell me what the basic difference between these 2 functions is?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`template_preprocess_search_result` is to process variables for `search-result.tpl.php` which will render output for each of the search result independently.

`template_preprocess_search_results` is to process variables for `search-results.tpl.php` which will render output after each of the search result is already rendered through `search-result.tpl.php`

For example, if there are 4 search results. for each of the results `search-result.tpl.php` will be used. and at the end `search-results.tpl.php` will be used. Ending up using `search-result.tpl.php` for 4 times for each of the results and `search-results.tpl.php` only once at the end.

Hope that is clear.

Comment: glad could help :D

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you want to change.

The one could be used for changing the markup for the actual result, for example headline + trimmed description, while the other is for all the results for example list, table or divs.

So you might need to use one or both, or maybe just use template files.